# Sybase difference between table reorg and index reorg

Tags: sybase, rdbms, sap-ase

I am not so aware about DBA concepts, but I see these 2 options come up with database fragmentation.

One is "table fragmentation" and other is "index fragmentation"

Being a front end developer, only guess I can take is, table fragmentation as it implies is the fragmentation in the physical data store. Index (NC) fragmentation refers to fragmentation in the index store.

I may be completely wrong here, the situation is there as large database about 100 tables and size is on GBs overall.

We had  a weekly reorg on fixed 50 odd tables - "reorg table" command every week.

Later we have changed from that to query fragmentation status of tables and reorg only those tables - this returns 3 or 4 tables and they were reorged.
Another step added was to check fragmentation status of indexes, and the for the indexes returned reorg is performed - "reorg index" command.

Thing is after the change the database has gone very poor performing. Cpu usages spike up and at times stalls the server instance going over 100%.

Seems there was a big difference when we reorged fixed 50 tables vs we started reorging table that were flagged in frag reports. 
Querying for fragmented indexes and performing reorg on them didn't seem to help much. Seems that previously when we reorged table, indexes on them were reorged implicitly, not sure, but explicit adding of this index reorg step doesn't make any difference.

Like said am a front end developer and I like to understand things in layman terms, with simple real life analogies, can this fragmentation stuff have a simple explanation?

Comment: The main command is `reorg`, then there are several options that can be performed at the table, index, and/or partition level. Newer versions of ASE have more options available. Without a good bit more info (ASE version, exact `reorg` options) it's hard to comment on exactly what's going on; take a look at the [reorg command](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/16.0.3.4/en-US/ab3c7eaebc2b10148427e96426d08c12.html) to see if this helps; as for the performance issue ... *shrug* ... hard to say without getting into (a lot) more performance related details.

Comment: hi, we are using sybase ase 15.7, so when we say reorg index, instead of saying reorg table what is defragmented? Is it that when we say reorg table, the actual pages containing data rows are aligned next to each other. And in case of reorg index, not the actual table pages, but the place where the index is stored is worked upon for defragmentation?

Comment: If you read the notes about the `reorg` command in that link I provided, you would see the `reorg` command has options that perform different actions ... reclaim space used by logically deleted rows, eliminating forwarded row pointers, removing empty space (ie, compacting), physically defragging bytes; so, which one is happening in your case will depend on which options you're providing to the `reorg` command; and since there's no `reorg table` or `reorg index` command, it's (still) hard to say what's happening in your case without the **ACTUAL** command you're running

Comment: Hi, previously we had reorg table  full rebuild on fixed 60 tables run  every weekend.
Now we do reorg index full rebuild. 
My understanding is that there are various types of pages, one of which is data pages that hold the actual data rows itself and other is index pages, which holds the copies of column values on which index is built and pointers to the page+row location of the physical record. If that's correct then, does it mean by reorg rebuild index, the defragmentation happens on index pages? Or am I totally confused and going in the wrong direction... :(